# Oracle SQL: Get all users in one table but not another and join to a third table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am wondering how to use oracle sql to get all the rows that are in one table but not another. The issue I am having is that the two tables don't have a field in common so I need to join to a third master table.

This is what I've tried which doesn't produce any errors but also produces 0 records which isn't possible but clearly I've done something wrong.

```
 SELECT a.USER_ID, c.AD_ID, c.CREATED_DATE_ FROM $A$ a, $C$ c, $B$ b 
 WHERE (b.USER_ID IS NULL AND a.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID)
```

I have three tables:

Table A has fields CUSTOMER_ID & USER_ID

Table B has field USER_ID

Table C has field CUSTOMER_ID

I need all the users that are in table C but not table B. They are all in Table A because that is the master list of users.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are no users in table c, you specifically say it only lists customers?

Comment: Table C has customers/users but only the CUSTOMER_ID field is used to identify them.

Comment: @TM3 . . . And what happens when you have multiple rows in `C` for a given customer in `C`?  Sample data and desired results are really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table_a
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_b WHERE table_b.user_id     = table_a.user_id    )
  AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_c WHERE table_c.customer_id = table_a.customer_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
select * from TableC tc
join TableA ta on tc.CUSTOMER_ID=ta.CUSTOMER_ID
left join TableB tb on tb.USER_ID=ta.USER_ID
where ta.USER_ID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select a.USER_ID, c.AD_ID, c.CREATED_DATE_
from a join
     c
     on a.customer_id = c.customer_id
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.user_id = a.user_id);
```

Comment: Does assume 1:1 relationship between A and C

Comment: @MatBailie . . . No, it answers the OP's question.  If the OP wants columns from `C`, then I assume s/he wants all matching rows.

Comment: `I need all the users that are in table C but not table B. They are all in Table A because that is the master list of users.`  If A is the master list of user then C could have a many:1 relationship with A.  It certainly does adapt the OP's attempt to solve the OP's requirement, but even that does not preclude the OP having made the assumption.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff ... This seems to work for me, You're correct C does have a 1:many relationship with A. Is your code pulling only one row of each user or all?